# how to get the stock status without loading the whole product-efficient way

Tags: out-of-stock, stock-status

I have the sku in the page and I want to see if product is in stock or out of stock and to do that I have done this:

```
  $firstProductId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('mysku');
                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                        $product->setId($firstProductId);
                        $inStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getIsInStock();
```

I want to know if I can achieve this without loading the whole product any other way which is more efficient or I am on the right path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can use this code which give stock in faster way using product id**

```
$model=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$model->getResource()->loadByProductId($model, $productId);
$data=$model->setOrigData();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data->getData());
```

**Out is  an array**

An exmaple:

```
Array
(
    [item_id] => 1868
    [product_id] => 889
    [stock_id] => 1
    [qty] => 5000.0000
    [min_qty] => 0.0000
    [use_config_min_qty] => 1
    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
    [backorders] => 0
    [use_config_backorders] => 1
    [min_sale_qty] => 1.0000
    [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 1
    [max_sale_qty] => 0.0000
    [use_config_max_sale_qty] => 1
    [is_in_stock] => 1
    [low_stock_date] => 
    [notify_stock_qty] => 
    [use_config_notify_stock_qty] => 1
    [manage_stock] => 0
    [use_config_manage_stock] => 1
    [stock_status_changed_auto] => 0
    [use_config_qty_increments] => 1
    [qty_increments] => 0.0000
    [use_config_enable_qty_inc] => 1
    [enable_qty_increments] => 0
    [is_decimal_divided] => 0
    [type_id] => simple
    [stock_status_changed_automatically] => 0
    [use_config_enable_qty_increments] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$firstProductId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('mysku');
$inStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $firstProductId)->getFirstItem()
```

This should do the trick.

Although, not sure how efficient it would be but can confirm this is magento way.